# Do Google reCAPTCHA V2 tokens expire?

Tags: javascript, token, recaptcha

I am using **Google reCAPTCHA V2** and verify the token on the server side as
described in

https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify

Do these tokens automatically expire? How long before they do?

Comment: From [the same document](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify) you linked to: “Each _reCAPTCHA_ user response token is **valid for two minutes**, and **can only be verified once** to prevent replay attacks.”

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on my own testing they are **one-time tokens**. Once you verified a token it becomes expired immediately.